# Place arbitrary sized circles in another shape/parallelogram

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, circle-pack

I want an algorithm to place a number of arbitrary (with min,max) radius circles inside another shape, mainly inside a rectangle, without overlapping and (seemingly) random position.

Comment: Use this to avoid overlap between circles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem (works with spheres too), you are welcome.

Comment: Does "orthogonal parallelogram" mean "rectangle"?

Comment: yes it does -.-' fixing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two constraints:

1. Circles should remain inside a rectangle
2. Circles should not overlap

**Keeping circles away from each other**

This one does not depend on details about the rectangle:

[image: Circles]

If the midpoints of the circles are closer to each other than the sum of their radiuses, the two circles intersect. Otherwise they do not (they may touch in case of equality). And you can use the Pythagorean theorem for calculating the distance.
If the radiuses are `r1` and `r2`, and the midpoints are `x1,y1` and `x2,y2`, the check would look like

```
if(Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) >= r1+r2)
  okay
else
  not okay
```

where `Math.sqrt()` calculates the square root of something (and calculcating the second power is done with simple multiplication here).

**Keeping circles inside a rectangle**

Here the radius has a role again: if the midpoint of a circle is closer to any border than its radius, it intersects with that border.

[image: Rectangle-Circle]

The simplest case is when the rectangle is axis-aligned, and starts from `0,0`. In this case it is pretty obvious that a circle with radius `r` and midpoint `x,y` can not have `x<r` or `y<r`, because in that case the circle would have some part in the negative x or y planes. The other limits are the `width` and `height` of the rectangle, `x+r>width` (or rather `x>width-r`) would result in the circle having some part "beyond" the limits of the rectangle.
This can be easily extended to an axis-aligned rectangle running from `x1,y1` to `x2,y2`:

```
if( x>=x1+r && x<=x2-r && y>=y1+r && y<=y2-r )
  okay
else
  not okay
```

However in reality you would not use this check, but generate circles which are inside a rectangle:

1. pick a radius `r` (between suitable min and max)
2. pick a point from the reduced rectangle with corners `x1+r, y1+r` and `x2-r, y2-r`

So it is just the classic task of generating a random number between some limits. If you happen to have a random number generator function `random()` generating fractions between 0 and 1, and limits `min` and `max`, `min+(max-min)*random()` is the expression you could use.

Put together in JavaScript:

```js
function stuff(){
  let ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cnv.width,cnv.height);
  lineStyle="black";
  ctx.strokeRect(0,0,cnv.width,cnv.height);
  
  let x1=ix1.valueAsNumber,y1=iy1.valueAsNumber;
  let x2=ix2.valueAsNumber,y2=iy2.valueAsNumber;
  let cnt=icnt.valueAsNumber;
  let rmin=irmin.valueAsNumber,rmax=irmax.valueAsNumber;
  
  ctx.fillStyle="lightgray";
  ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,x2-x1,y2-y1);

  ctx.fillStyle="blue";
  let giveup=Date.now()+3000;
  let circles=[];
  while(circles.length<cnt && Date.now()<giveup){
    let r=rmin+(rmax-rmin)*Math.random();
    let x=x1+r+(x2-r-x1-r)*Math.random();
    let y=y1+r+(y2-r-y1-r)*Math.random();
    let okay=true;
    for(let c of circles)
      if(Math.sqrt((x-c.x)*(x-c.x)+(y-c.y)*(y-c.y))<r+c.r){
        okay=false;
        break;
      }
    if(okay){
      circles.push({x:x,y:y,r:r});
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }  
  ctx.strokeRect(x1,y1,x2-x1,y2-y1);
}
stuff();
```

```css
input{width:50px}
```

```html
x1:<input id="ix1" type="number" min="0" max="600" value="50" onchange="stuff()">
y1:<input id="iy1" type="number" min="0" max="150" value="10" onchange="stuff()">
x2:<input id="ix2" type="number" min="0" max="600" value="400" onchange="stuff()">
y2:<input id="iy2" type="number" min="0" max="150" value="140" onchange="stuff()">
#:<input id="icnt" type="number" min="0" max="50" value="10" onchange="stuff()">
rmin:<input id="irmin" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="20" onchange="stuff()">
rmax:<input id="irmax" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="50" onchange="stuff()">

<canvas id="cnv" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
```

As it is easy to pick parameters which are either unsolvable at all, or can be unsolvable after placing the first few circles in an unfortunate way, the code has a time limit, and gives up the work after 3 seconds.

Comment: This is nicely explained and pretty straightforward but as i said to Jesse Li, this seems a bit "brute force". Isn't there a mathematical way to check if the circles fit then place them in the coordinates that they fit and if there is a lot of room give them some leeway? maybe treat circles as cubes with side radius and check if the total area of the circles is less than the area of the shape? also only rectangle is covered,how would you go at it with different shapes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will fit your needs, but this is one way to go about it, essentially brute forcing it and assuming you have a polygon (no curves):

1. Find a bounding rectangle for the polygon. (I think you just need to iterate around all points, and keep the maximum and minimum x and y values.)
2. Generate a circle with random radius and location.
3. Check whether the circle center is inside the polygon - see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/
4. Check whether the circle intersects with any lines - see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275529/check-if-line-intersects-with-circles-perimeter
5. Check whether the circle intersects with any other circles using the Pythagorean theorem. (credit to tevemadar)
6. Repeat steps 2 through 5 until you have enough circles or it continually fails (probably means that there's no more space).

Comment: That's somewhere along the lines of my first thoughts, but it's a bit too "brute force" and by randomly placing the circles the only way to stop checking for positions is after a number of failures. Some way to check if there is space for the next circle maybe?

Comment: You could try to keep track of all points (or enough points, such that rounding isn't too much of an issue) inside the polygon, and cross them out when there's a circle center that is closer than the minimum radius + radius of that circle. If all points are crossed out, it'll be impossible to add another circle. Don't forget to also cross out points too close to the edge.